# Typeset in TextMate has a PATH error

Tags: errors, mac, textmate

I downloaded Textmate (1.5.10) on a new MacBookPro (MacOSX 10.6.7) after using it to typeset LaTeX on my old MacBook. I saved my document folders on my new computer in the same document folder structure and was unable to typeset the `.tex` documents. I got the response:

The current PATH is:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Please add the directory containing “kpsewhich” to PATH in TextMate's Shell Variables preferences.

In my TextMate preferences, Advanced>Shell Variables> - I have four categories checked off: `PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`, `PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, `_MyCompanyName__ TM_ORGANIZATION__NAME`, & (I tried adding) `MY_VARIABLE /usr/texbin`

When I click on the Terminal link to "Set PATH and Relaunch", this is what I get:

```
Last login: Fri Jun 17 16:06:39 on console
defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakShellVariables -array-add "{ enabled = 1; variable = PATH; value = '$PATH'; }" && open "/Users/annlmontgomery/Downloads/TextMate.app"
Ann-Montgomerys-MacBook-Pro:~ annlmontgomery$ defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakShellVariables -array-add "{ enabled = 1; variable = PATH; value = '$PATH'; }" && open "/Users/annlmontgomery/Downloads/TextMate.app"
Ann-Montgomerys-MacBook-Pro:~ annlmontgomery$
```

But I don't know what to do this step - I'm just learning LaTeX and have no programming experience.

additional note:
I do have MacTex and I included "/usr/texbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin" in the Shell Variables preferences and when I typeset, now I get "env: ruby: No such file or directory" ...any ideas? –

additional note: I have TexShop 2.41 installed

additional note:

in Preferences>Shell Variables - I now have

```
PATH /usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin/

PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin

PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/texbin

PATH /usr/texbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin

PATH /usr/bin/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

and when I Typeset - I get "env: ruby: No such file or directory"
BTW thanks for everyone's efforts

Comment: Did you install MacTeX?

Comment: I use TextMate and in  TextMate's Shell Variables preferences. : I 've `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin` in the terminal : $ echo $PATH  gives
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin.  When you install MacTeX, the PATH must contain /usr/texbin

Comment: You just need to add `/usr/texbin` to your `PATH`. Either make a new path variable or add `/usr/texbin:` to the front (or `:/usr/texbin` to the end) of one of the existing ones.

Comment: While the path can go wrong, I still think we need to know first that MacTeX is installed at all. That is far from clear from the question.

Comment: You are missing `/usr/bin` from your PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded TextMate and changed the only PATH in the preferences to read

```
/usr/texbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

It worked. You might add other directories to the PATH, but remember to separate them by colons. For example

```
/usr/texbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone...so for future cases...this is what I did:

1. Uninstalled everything: in Finder - control click on TextMate and TexShop and selected 'show package contents' and dragged that to trash
2. In Finder - User/Library/ dragged TexShop to trash
3. In Finder - User/Preference/ dragged to trash `com.macromate...' files and`TexShop' files
4. Emptied trash
5. Redownloaded TexShop and TextMate and installed them
6. In TextMate Preference>Advanced>Shell Variables unselected the PATH provided and created a new PATH and inserted the pathway above from egen `/usr/texbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`
7. Closed everything and restarted the computer
8. Everything works...again, thanks to everyone for your help (esp over the weekend)...

Comment: nice to know it worked. I guess that trashing TextMate and TeXShop is a bit drastic and probably it's not needed. Moreover, TeXShop is completely independent from the TeX distribution. Also restarting should not be needed: you've a Mac, not a W. box. `:-)`

Comment: I just re-downloaded Textmate and deleted the the /Users/yo/Library/Application Scripts/ folder and everything worked fine again. (note: all your preferences will be wiped when doing this)